# How to associate values from one array to another array as keys?

Tags: php, arrays

So, to simply put it, it looks like this:

#### Array1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
    [2] => email
)
```

#### Array2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => paula
    [2] => paula@paula.com

    [3] => 2
    [4] => martin
    [5] => martin@google.com

    [6] => 3
    [7] => kasandra
    [8] => kasandra@google.com

    [9] => 4
    [10] => helena
    [11] => helena@google.com

    [12] => 5
    [13] => sophia
    [14] => sophia@google.com

    [15] => 6
    [16] => denis
    [17] => denis@google.com
)
```

How to make those values from Array1 as keys in Array2 accordingly so that the end result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => paula
    [email] => paula@paula.com

    [id] => 2
    [name] => martin
    [email] => martin@google.com

    [id] => 3
    [name] => kasandra
    [email] => kasandra@google.com

    [id] => 4
    [name] => helena
    [email] => helena@google.com

    [id] => 5
    [name] => sophia
    [email] => sophia@google.com

    [id] => 6
    [name] => denis
    [email] => denis@google.com
)
```

Comment: In your sample you are overwriting on name and email index ..

Comment: You can't have same keys in array.

Comment: I am not overwriting anything, I just have those two arrays....and i need to assoiciate the keys

Comment: Assume I have that third array. Now I'm writing `$array['email']`. Which one will it print?

Comment: Actually I need to have this as JSON objects `{"id": 1, "name: "paula", "email": "paula@google.com" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a for loop with step 3

```
  $numCoords  = count($array2)/3
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numCoords; $i++ ){
    $array[$i]['id'] = $array2[$i*3]; 
    $array[$i]['name'] = $array2[($i*3)+1]; 
    $array[$i]['email'] = $array2[($i*3)+2]; 
  }
```

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: Is it true or false that I can't have same keys in PHP array?

Comment: @lewis4u True, you can't have the same key. The newer will overwrite the old one.

Comment: @lewis4u  . i don't uderstand  you comment

Comment: @scaisEdge which comment

Comment: @lewis4u  "Is it true or false that I can't have same keys in PHP array? "

Comment: You have a (typo) syntax error here `$array2[($i*3)+2;]` :)

Comment: @scaisEdge it was a boolean question because "maybe" or "it depends" are not possible for the answer. So the answer was: True, you can't have duplicate keys in PHP array.

Comment: @Syscall  .. thanks ..  correct  .. the OP had corrected  the answer

Comment: @scaisEdge what exactly is `$array` variable in your for loop? Should I declare it as empty array before the loop or?

Comment: the array where you obtain the result .. should not be necessary declare it ..but you can decalre properly of course .. you have error on $array?

Comment: @scaisEdge How can I show you the result? Should I post it in my question??

Comment: you can use var_dump($array)   .. and add  the result in question if this is useful ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167999/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `array_chunk` and get used to numeric indexes,
but if you really want to have them as words you may map them:

```
$keys = [
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'name',
    2 => 'email'
];

$chunked = array_chunk($array2, $length=3);
$result = array_map(function ($chunk) {
    global $keys;
    return array_combine($keys, $chunk);
}, $chunked);
```

Comment: where do you come from ptica?

Comment: How to make this more dynamic? For example what if I have different number of attributes every time? instead of id, name and email there could be also additional properties